# whats is the maximum memory can be allocated to a Vector of float in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

What is the maximum number of float elements that can be stored in a vector? In C++, I am using Ubuntu 14 platform, Core i7(4 physical cores) and 8GB ram

Answer (score 1):

The *theoretical* maximum size of a vector supported by the implementation is given by the function `std::vector::max_size`

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/max_size

How much you can allocate in this vector before *your* system runs out of memory, has no predictable answer.